# Кнопка в определенных координатах

Tags: java

**Суть:** нужна кнопка которая появляется при определённом событии в 2D игре(не меню). Не всплывающее окно и не JButton.

**Как я хочу чтобы это выглядело в игре:** я подхожу к NPC и появляется картинка, которая предлагает нажать клавишу [E] чтобы поговорить с ним. Или к двери, чтобы открыть её.

**Какая помощь необходима:** объяснить, хотя бы на слова, как можно появление этой кнопки реализовать.

P.S.: Как рассчитать дистанцию между игроком и NPC я знаю.

Comment: Создаете кнопку и кидаете ее на layout - panel.add(btn); Далее указываете координаты btn.setLocation(0,0); Либо при создании кнопки  использовать setBounds()

Comment: А какой фреймворк вы используете? Как рисуете в окне?

Comment: вручную пишу с помощью библиотек java.awt и javax.swing. возможно я не понял вопроса, недавно в программировании.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно при приближении создать JLabel, передать на него фокус, задать ему слушатель клавиатуры, и по нажатию E делать следующие действия. На самом JLabel написать ваше сообщение.

Answer (score 0):

Добился результата на половину: когда подхожу, нажимаю на кнопку и открывается окно квеста.
Позже додумаю как показывать картинку с надписью "действовать" или просто текст. 
Может кому будет интересно как я это сделал:

```
if(OrangeNpc.talk){

    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_E && !OrangeNpc.opened) {
        System.out.println("Speaking with npc");
        OrangeNpc.talk1 = true;
    }

    }else if (code == KeyEvent.VK_E && !OrangeNpc.talk && OrangeNpc.opened){
     OrangeNpc.talk1 = false; OrangeNpc.opened = false;
    }
```

Если **дистанция игрока равна 85** автоматически включается булен **"talk"** в классе нпца, и также если нажата **клавиша [E]**  и **Окно разговора с нпц не открыто**, то включить булен **"talk1"**, который в другом классе **открывает Окно разговора** и даёт булену **"opened" значение тру.**

Дальше, чтобы закрыть окно, если нажата **клавиша [E]** и **дистанция** между объектами **больше 85** **("talk" автоматически становится false)**  и **Окно разговора открыто**, то выключается **"talk1"** из-за которого **перестаёт отображаться** Окно разговора.